# How many HttpClient instances can I create?

Tags: c#, httpclient

In the [official Microsoft documentation for HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2), it is stated that

> HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout the life of an application.

We are the process of refactoring all HttpClient instances in a legacy project to use a static HttpClient. However, there appears some confusion among the team over the quoted sentence. Is it meant that there should be a single HttpClient class instance in some helper class as a singleton? Or should every class that uses the HttpClient have its own static instance? Examples:

Example 1:

```
public static class SingletonHttpClient
{
    public static HttpClient = new HttpClient();
}

public class SomeClass
{
    .....
    SingletonHttpClient.HttpClient.GetAsync(url);
    .....
}
```

Example 2:

```
public class ClassA
{
    private static HttpClient = new HttpClient();
}

public class ClassB
{
    private static HttpClient = new HttpClient();
}
```

What is the intended way by Microsoft? Or is there another way I'm missing?

Comment: \please check this https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/330364/should-we-create-a-new-single-instance-of-httpclient-for-all-requests

Comment: We use multiple HttpClients for different purposes (e.g. different baseUrl, different authentications, etc.), but you should create the minimum and not for every request a new one.

Comment: HttpClient can create deadlock issue. So be carrefull with it. According to your context if you got only 2 or 3 class 1 httpClient by class is ok. Also put a using before it, HttpClient is IDisposable.

Comment: @LeBigCat You should read the documentation page, you might be surprised. HttpClients should *not* be disposed in the way you described.

Comment: Well as we use singleton this is not really important but yes indeed, in case of httpClient is newed (no static context), you 100% right.

Comment: Use HttpClientFactory